# Adding one element from a list to next,after that to next etc

Tags: python, list

Here is an example from a simple list

```
mylist = [2,5,9,12,50]
```

I want to add the first element, in this case 2, to the element next to it. It's the number 5. The outcome (2+5=7) should be added to the next element, number 9 in my example. The outcome should be added to the next element etc...

I have this snippet right now which is working, but there must be a simpler and better way:

```
newlist = [5, 9, 12 , 50]
counts = 0
a = 2
while (counts < 5):
    a = a + mylist[n]
    print a
    counts = counts + 1
```

output is:

```
7
16
28
78
```

next snippet:

```
mylist = [2, 5, 9, 12, 50]
lines_of_file = [4, 14, 20, 25, 27]
sum_list = []
outcome = 0

for element in mylist:
    outcome = outcome + element
    sum_list.append(outcome)

fopen = ('test.txt', 'r+')
write = fopen.readlines()

for element, line in zip(sum_list, lines_of_file):
    write[line] = str(element)

fopen.writelines()
fopen.close()
```

Comment: I'm new to programming sorry.I need every outcome to write it in a file.

Comment: Which Python version are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna write it to specific positions in a file, try this:

Let's say you have a `numbers.txt` file, with 10 lines, like so:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Then use this:

```
original_list = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
lines_to_write = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]  # Lines you want to write the results in
total = 0
sum_list = list()

# Get the list of cumulative sums
for element in original_list:
    total = total + element
    sum_list.append(total)
# sum_list = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

# Open and read the file
with open('numbers.txt', 'rw+') as file:
    file_lines = file.readlines()
    for element, line in zip(sum_list, lines_to_write):
        file_lines[line-1] = '{}\n'.format(element)
    file.seek(0)
    file.writelines(file_lines)
```

You then get `numbers.txt` like so:

```
0
1
0
4
0
9
0
16
0
25
```

Comment: That's also a nice solution.But what if i want to write the values for example in line 10,12,15,17 and 20 in a file?

Comment: @Phil I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. You say you want to build the cumulative sum list, but only write a few of the results in a file?

Comment: Sorry @Gabe i editet my code.Can take a look at it if you want.I want this in a for loop if it's possible

Comment: @Phil I just edited the anwer to what I think you're looking for

Comment: thanks Gabe,but i figured how i can do it.I used zip in my for loop.I edited code again and it works!!

Comment: No i was wrong.I just wrote the normal values of mylist into my file!!Your are precisely right with your code.Thank you for my time now my problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

You can do something simple like this:

```
>>> mylist = [2,5,9,12,50]
>>> 
>>> total = 0  # initialize a running total to 0
>>> for i in mylist:  # for each i in mylist
...     total += i  # add i to the running total
...     print total  # print the running total
... 
2
7
16
28
78
```

---

[`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org) has a nice function for doing this, namely [`cumsum()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.cumsum(mylist)
array([ 2,  7, 16, 28, 78])
```

You can use `list(...)` to turn the array back into a list.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i was looking for.I tried with a for loop.But it seems i have done it to complicated

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) to add up all values of a sequence:

```
>>> sum([2,5,9,12,50])
78
```

But if you wanted to keep a running total, just loop through your list:

```
total = 2
for elem in newlist:
    total += a
    print total
```

That also can be used to build a list:

```
total = 2
cumsum = []
for elem in newlist:
    total += a
    cumsum.append(total)
```

Comment: It looks like the OP wants a cumulative sum.

Comment: @arshajii: And what is a cumulative sum when not adding the next value to the sum so far?

Comment: He wants to display the value at each stage.

Comment: Problem solved thank you a lot...Answers will be accepted in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the possible solutions:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

mylist = [2,5,9,12,50]
runningSum = 0

for index in range(0,len(mylist)):
    runningSum = runningSum + mylist[index]
    print runningSum
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version:

```
newlist = [2,5,9,12,50]

for i in range(1,len(newlist)):
    print sum(newlist[:i+1])
```

Note that it doesn't include the `2`, like you wanted.
It might calculate sums over and over again though (I don't know how smart the compiler is).

Output:

```
7
16
28
78
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to display the first item in the list (number 2), then this solution will do it:

```
mylist = [2,5,9,12,50]

it = iter(mylist)
total = it.next() # total = 2, first item
for item in it:
    total += item
    print total
```